# Assign multiple variables with list values

Tags: python

how to assign multiple variables using a list? For example, a list `a=[1,2,3, ..., 5]`, I would like that three variables `var1, var2, var3, ..., var5` respectively has value `1,2, 3, ..., 5`.

Answer (score -1):

We can use the following solution:

```
a=[1,2,3,...,5]
var1, var2, var3, ..., var5 = [a[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: or simply `var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = a`